# Is there a way to directly read a number from file to unsigned char variable?

Tags: c++, file, char, unsigned-char

As in reading "117" in a text file and giving the variable value 'u', not '1'. And I know I can do it simply and quickly by reading the value to an int and then casting it to unsigned char, I just need to know if I can do it directly.

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but "casting it to unsigned char" isn't necessary; `int` is convertible to `unsigned char`, so no cast is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Try `scanf` with format specifier `hhud` (cf. [scanf format specifiers at cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/))

```cpp
unsigned char c;
scanf("%hhud", &c);
```

In the terminal, I enter `117`, and variable `c` then shows value `'u'` in the debugger...